# Genymotion doesn't start in OS X

Tags: macos, virtualbox, genymotion

I am using Genymotion 2.5 with Virtual Box 5.0.0 in MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015).

When I run Genymotion it says,

```
Unable to load VirtualBox engine.

Make sure that it is properly installed before starting Genymotion.
```

Then I checked the log file sin genymotion-log.zip and found that there is an error in general-VBoxSVC.log

```
00:00:00.131500 nspr-2   failed to create vboxnet0, error (0x80004005)
00:00:00.131684 nspr-2   VD: VDInit finished
00:00:05.137155 Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945} aComponent={VirtualBoxWrap} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a bug,  Downgrade VirtualBox to  4.3.26
(remove VirtualBox 5.0.0 with CleanMyMac beforehand)

Answer (score 2):

You can also start Genymotion with root permissions from the Terminal, e.g.
`sudo /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/genymotion`. Works for me with VirtualBox 5.0.0 and Genymotion 2.5.0.

**Edit: After upgrading to Genymotion 2.5.2, it just works, without `sudo`.**